# Fermenter foaming over

Tags: yeast, krausen, pitch

I’m doing a porter, went through all steps and got to pitching the yeast in the bucket. After only a few hours my fermenter seriously bubbled over. Thoughts?

Comment: Your yeast was very healthy.  How much yeast did you use?  How many gallons or liters of porter did you brew?  How high did you fill the bucket?  Did you leave any space in the bucket for foam?

Comment: You need about 20% head space in the fermenter. If you control the temperature, try lowering it to slow down fermentation. If not, your best bet is to move the fermenter to a bathtub or such to contain the spills.

Answer (score 2):

Not particularly worrying. If temperature is under control and yeast amount is right, then head space as others say - as well as using a blow-off tube rather than a traditional air lock.